# No reports a 550 recipient rejected from MailApp

Tags: google-apps-script

When sending mail using MailApp.sendEmail() or GmailApp.sendEmail() from App Script to a non-existent address I do not get an email informing about the error. I would expect an email to the account that sends reporting problem: 550  recipient rejected.

```
function testNonExistentAddress() {
  var _recipient = 'nonexistentaddress@myexample.net';
  var _subject = 'TEST FROM MAILAPP APPSCRIPT';
  var _body = 'TEST';
  MailApp.sendEmail(_recipient, _subject, _body);
}
```

Comment: There's a mail server at myexample.net (a google domain), so you don't get a 550 when sending there from the gmail UI either. You should use one of the [IANA's Special Use Domain Names](http://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml) instead, e.g. `test@invalid.com` will return a 550 error when used from the UI. (But not from apps script.) I would bet that google chooses to block these responses to thwart spambots.

Comment: I tried with multiple domains, some where I have control over the email accounts that exist, but for nonexistent accounts do not receive the 550 recipient rejected (in any case) when sending from Apps Script. Strange case because it uses the same active Gmail account. If it is a limitation should at least be documented.

Comment: For anyone interested in following it, William raised [Issue 2965](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2965) for this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it is not sending it from you.  It's simply bouncing it off a Google server.  You will also notice that it doesn't appear in your sent folder, and that you need to declare who the email is coming from.  I also bcc myself on the emails that my apps send so that I have a record in my mail account.

Nothing to be done, I believe. Other than checking the issue tracker / feature request.  Or calling a third party system to ensure that the email address is real.

Comment: Email sent if left in the sent folder, so do use the account to send the emails. The same problem happens when using GmailApp.sendEmail().

Comment: I'll echo William - this answer is not correct. Messages sent using MailApp.sendMail are sent from the active gmail account, and do appear in the sent mail folder, since about July 19 2013. (This wasn't always the case, see [Issue 674](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=674).

Comment: Ah, since June 19th, 2013.  Sorry for the old info.  Would it be best to delete this answer or are these comments enough of a correction?

Comment: You can go either way - [opinions vary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22630/should-i-remove-a-wrong-answer-peer-pressure). My vote would be to update the info first - if there's not enough left, then the answer tends to become a comment instead.