# How to stop MailApp.sendEmail from sending myself a copy of the email

Tags: google-apps-script

We are using Google Scripts to send emails after Google Forms are submitted. In the last day or two, we started receiving email delivery failures every time a form was submitted and the script ran. It is only unable to deliver messages to one account(sender@mydomain.com), which happens to be the account that the script is running as. However, this account should not be receiving a copy of this form anyways. All of the email addresses that are in the "To" field are getting the email with no issue, we are just trying to find out why we are getting this error message.

We are using the MailApp.sendEmail function and have been for years without any problem. We can't use the GmailApp functions because this account is not able to use Gmail and we've never needed to be able to in order to send emails.

In the script, when I add sender@mydomain.com to the To list, I receive the email and do not get any error messages. When I remove it from the To list, the rest of the recipients continue to receive the email but I get that error message again for sender@mydomain.com.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {


  var replyToAddr = "no_reply@mydomain.com";
  var emailAddress = e.values[2]; // + ", sender@mydomain.com";

  //Removed section that creates PDF, stores as the variable pdf

  var subject = "Form Request from " + e.values[1];
  var messageHtml = "<font size = 3><font face = arial>Form Request from: " + e.values[1]; 
  var messagePlain = messageHtml.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messagePlain, {htmlBody: messageHtml, name: "Sender", attachments: pdf, replyTo: replyToAddr});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird to me that MailApp was working on an account that doesn't have Gmail enabled as MailApp affects the email sent Gmail quota but then I found [No reports a 550 recipient rejected from MailApp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17422924/1595451). The [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17435208/1595451) at this time looks to be wrong as MailApp sent emails are saved as sent emails on Gmail mailbox of the effective user that ran the script.